# Copy Random Rows Keeping Unique Data From a column user and again in decision column if decision is yes get 10% if decision no than 10% total 10% rows

Tags: vba, excel

want to get 10 % row from column user and decision for each user if decision yes than 10% if his data and if decision no Than 10% of data i am getting only unique row from user column not from decision column.

```
Sub Random10_EveryName()
Randomize 'Initialize Random number seed

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Copy Sheet1 to new sheet
 Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

'Clear old data in Sheet 2
 Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents

'Determine Number of Rows in Sheet1 Column A
 numRows = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(Rows.Count, _
 "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Sort new sheet by Column E
 Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells.Sort _
 key1:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("O1:D" & numRows), _
 order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

'Initialize numNames & startRow variable
 numNames = 1
 startRow = 2

'Loop through sorted names, count number of current Name
 For nameRows = startRow To numRows
 If Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(nameRows, "D") = _
 Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(nameRows + 1, "D") Then
 numNames = numNames + 1
 Else:
 endRow = startRow + numNames - 1

'Generate Random row number within current Name Group
 nxtRnd = Int((endRow - startRow + 1) * _
 Rnd + startRow)

'Copy row to Sheet2, Delete copied Name
 dstRow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 Sheets(Sheets.Count).Rows(nxtRnd).EntireRow.Copy _
 Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(dstRow, 1)
 Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(nxtRnd, "D").ClearContents

'Set Start Row for next Name Group, reset numNames variable
 startRow = endRow + 1
 numNames = 1
 End If
 Next

'Sort new sheet by Column O
 Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells.Sort _
 key1:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("O1:E" & numRows), _
 order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

'Determine Number of Remaining Names in new sheet Column O
 numNamesleft = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(Rows.Count, _
 "E").End(xlUp).Row - 1

'Determine 10% of total entries from Sheet1
 percRows = _
 WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((numRows - 1) * 0.2, 0)

'Determine how many extra rows are needed to reach 10% of total
 unqNames = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, _
 "E").End(xlUp).Row - 1
 extRows = percRows - unqNames

'Warn user if number of Unique Names exceeds 10% of Total Entires
 If extRows < 0 Then
 MsgBox "Number of Unique Names Exceeds 10% of Total Entries"
'Delete new sheet
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Sheets(Sheets.Count).Delete
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Exit Sub
 End If

'Extract Random entries from remaining names to reach 10%
'
'Allocate elements in Array
 ReDim MyRows(extRows)
'Create Random numbers and fill array
 For nxtRow = 1 To extRows
getNewRnd:
'Generate Random row numbers within current Name Group
 nxtRnd = Int((numNamesleft - 2 + 1) * _
 Rnd + 2)
'Loop through array, checking for Duplicates
 For chkRnd = 1 To nxtRow
'Get new number if Duplicate is found
 If MyRows(chkRnd) = nxtRnd Then GoTo getNewRnd
 Next
'Add element if Random number is unique
 MyRows(nxtRow) = nxtRnd
 Next

'Loop through Array, copying rows to Sheet2
 For copyrow = 1 To extRows
 dstRow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 Sheets(Sheets.Count).Rows(MyRows(copyrow)).EntireRow.Copy _
 Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(dstRow, 1)
 Next

'Delete new sheet
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Sheets(Sheets.Count).Delete
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Can you try and simplify your question? To be honest the only thing I understand is that you want 10% of something. A small example could be helpful.

Comment: see i have two columns one is user name and other one is decision now for each unique user i want 10% data.. for example if user name is rohit and decision yes than 10% random of  all rows where user decision was yes again for no 10% all the row of same user where decision is NO.

Answer (score 0):

```
SEE I HAVE DONE HERE CAN YOU MAKE ANY CHANGE SO THAT IF VALUE= NO DEFECT THAN COPY ONLY 10% FROM THOSE ROW
Sub test()
Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, R As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, n As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents
n = 1
lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
 For R = 2 To lr


 If Range("D" & R).Value = "gadrooa" And Range("E" & R).Value = "NO_DEFECT" Then
 Rows(R).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & n + 1)
 n = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


 End If
 Next R
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```